# Resource.fromAutoCloseable not invoking the inside action

Tags: scala, io, scala-cats, cats-effect

In my code I need to create a database and create some tables in it using cats.effect. The code as following,

```
  def createTable[F[_]: Async]: Resource[F, ResultSet] = {

    val createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warehouses (\n"
                + " id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                + " name text NOT NULL,\n"
                + " capacity real\n"
                + ");";
    for {
      mutex <- Resource.eval(Mutex[F])
      connection <- Resource.fromAutoCloseable(Async[F].blocking {
        DriverManager.getConnection(s"jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/db/test.sqlite")
      })
      rs <-
        Resource
          .fromAutoCloseable {
            mutex.lock.surround {
              Async[F].blocking {
                connection.prepareStatement(
                  createTableQuery
                )
              }
            }
          }
    }yield{
      rs.executeQuery()
    }

  }
```

But unfortunately, the database not creating and I found out that its not execute the  `DriverManager.getConnection(s"jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/db/test.sqlite")` part. Can I know why it's not executing?

method called as below,

```
createTable[IO].use{
  rs => IO(rs)
}
```

Comment: No offense but you need to read again the basics of Cats Effect: you're getting an `IO` as result of the `use` call, this is a "representation" of the program, it's not executed yet. You'll have to `run` it for all the code you're written to actually do something.

Comment: @GaëlJ why not make this an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: What is the meta-problem you are tying to model here?

Comment: @MSmedberg I would need to expand a bit more with some links and code samples in an answer. I'm on my phone, not able to easily do it. But feel free to give a more complete answer if you'd like :)

Comment: Why are you doing this by hand instead of using doobie? jdbc is already wrapped with an extremely mature production-ready high-level interface with more than half a decade of work in it